# Lotus formula to filter calendar entries containing certain text

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I'm fairly new to Lotus Script and Formula language. I'm trying to make a view that only shows certain calendar entries - the view selection looks like

```
  SELECT Form = "Appointment" | AppointmentType = "0" | AppointmentType = "2"| AppointmentType = "3"
```

It's pretty simple but seem to works okay. Next step is that I do not want to show documents where part of the subject contain "Accepted:". How is this achievable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`@Contains`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONTAINS.html) for this purpose.

```
!@Contains("Subject"; "Accepted:")
```

You'll need a logical And with the existing selection:

```
SELECT (Form = "Appointment" | AppointmentType = "0" | AppointmentType = "2"| AppointmentType = "3") & (!@Contains("Subject"; "Accepted:"))
```

Comment: Agreed. My guess would be that the original SELECT isn't correct, that it should be SELECT Form = "Appointment" & (AppointmentType = "0" | AppointmentType = "2"| AppointmentType = "3") or, in shorthand: SELECT Form = "Appointment" & AppointmentType = "0":"2":"3"